# Assigning Union's fields

Tags: c++, struct, setter, unions

i have created a structure uses an union as its field. Here is a small code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Type
{
    STR, 
    INT
};

struct MyStruct
{
    Type type;
    union Value
    {
        std::string str;
        int i;
        Value(){}
        ~Value(){};

    } value;
    void setType(Type type)
    {
        this->type = type;
    }
    void setValue(const std::string& data)
    {
        this->value.str = data;
    }
    MyStruct(){}
    ~MyStruct(){}
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct my;
    my.setType(Type::STR);
    my.setValue("Hallo");

   std::cout << my.value.str << std::endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Setting Value i got an error (Segmentation fault (core dumped)) What is the right way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: It's a horrible idea to union a string with an int.

Comment: Your `union` may have a data member with a non trivial special member function. See: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Comment: You should not have separate `setType` and `setValue` functions, instead it should set both in one go (because you need to inspect the existing type to know whether you need to call constructors and destructors).  You'd be better off looking at sample code of how to use a union that contains a string, instead of guessing / posting questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be careful.  Non-POD types in unions are asking for trouble.  Saying that, this is supported in C++11, provided you only initialise at most one member.  That means you'll have to change how things work.

Trivially, to fix your program as it stands right now, you just use placement new:

```
void setValue(const std::string& data)
{
    new (&value.str) std::string(data);
}
```

But now, if you want to set a *different* member later, you will need to use placement delete on the string.  To achieve that, you need to know that there was a string there to begin with.  So you cannot easily separate the `setValue` from the `setType`.

One option (not particularly nice) is:

```
private:
  void setType( type ) {
      // Destruct existing type
      switch( this->type ) {
      case STR:
          value.str.~std::string();
          break;
      default:;
      }

      this->type = type;
  }

public:
  void setValue( const std::string& data )
  {
      setType( STR );
      new (&value.str) std::string(data);
  }

  void setValue( int data )
  {
      setType( INT );
      value.i = data;
  }
```

And don't forget to properly destruct the value in `~MyStruct`.

Comment: It may be problematic to call the string destructor on an unconstructed string object. Or what is the initial value of type?

Comment: Well, yes I didn't mention that but should have.  Obviously the initial value of `type` should be something sensible.  I would consider opting for a 'default' enumeration of `NO_TYPE`.  Or just set it to `INT` with a value of zero.

Comment: My point: Maybe `this->type` is zero on default constructed objects as in the example code. If you assign a string object with `setValue` then the destructor will be called on an uninitialized / unconstructed string object. Yes, it would be good to take care of that in the default constructor, `NO_TYPE` would be fine.

Comment: The value of `type` is undefined in the OP's code.  If it was expicitly set to `STR`, then the string would need to be constructed too.  If it wasn't set at all, it's undefined behaviour.  When I said set to `INT` with _a value of zero_ I meant to initialise the union's `i` member to zero.

Answer (score 4):

Although C++11 does allow you to have classes inside a union, it is generally considered to be bad practice, because it's a minefield of undefined behavior.

If your union's constructor does not construct the union's member which is a class instance -- as is the case with your sample code -- by definition that class instance never gets constructed.

Your code then attempts to use the union's class member. Namely its operator=. Because this class instance has not been constructed, this becomes undefined behavior, which results in your crash.

Stick with `POD`s in your unions. Less grief.

Comment: This is kind of confusing due to terminology used. You're saying, presumably, that the union's `str` member needs to be constructed, yeah? _"the union's class instance"_ phrases like this are quite ambiguous in this context. Can you tidy up the answer a bit?

Comment: It is certainly possible, in a union. That's what a union means, after all. Try loading the sample code in a debugger, step to it, and see for yourself that std::string's constructor will not be invoked here. Welcome to C++.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my comment already - thought you were referring to members of the class, not of the union. Because, well, that's what you originally said :) (Although a union is a kind of class) _"Welcome to C++"_ not sure whether joking or trolling, but I've been using C++ for quite some time!

Comment: Me too, and I still learn something new every day. I guess today it's your turn!

Comment: I haven't learnt anything yet today, except that you are good at ninja-editing your answers to make them less confusing :)

Comment: That a class instance may not get constructed, if it's a part of the union.

Comment: I knew that already; it's pretty basic C++. However, it's not what you originally said. I believe your wording was something like "class member" instead of "class instance", though I can't remember exactly now! I still think this answer could do with some clarifying for upvoteworthiness

Comment: The main part - answers the question - is: Stick with PODs in your unions. +1